# What is the licensing cost of Datastax Enterprise version and MongoDB Enterprise edition?

Tags: mongodb, datastax-enterprise

What is the licensing cost of DataStax Enterprise version and MongoDB Enterprise edition? I have searched through and could not find answers to this. Please let me know if any one has the details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise-advanced

> Download the MongoDB Enterprise Advanced Datasheet for more information or contact us for pricing details.

You need to contact sales it looks like.